# How to make a simple bookmark on HTC Wildfire S?

Tags: browser, bookmarks, htc-wildfire-s

I am in the browser on my HTC Wildfire S.

I want to make a bookmark of the current page and save it to my desktop (main screen).

I press and hold down the URL and it gives me the choices:

- share page (twitter, facebook, etc.)
- copy page url

I would also expect it to give me the option "save bookmark".

**How can I make a bookmark of a web page?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add the current page as a bookmark, in the browser:

Menu->Bookmarks->Add Bookmark

Then you can long click the bookmark and select 'Add Shortcut to Home' which will add an icon for the bookmark on the desktop. Alternatively, long click on the desktop, then select

Add Item->Shortcut->Bookmark